# How can I pass data to a Bootstrap modal when calling via javascript?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I know how to pass data to a Bootstrap modal when using a button, using data attributes, thus I can eg pass a **context** of 'OPS' via a data-context attribute as:

```
<button id="xx" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#xx" data-context="OPS">xx</button>
```

How do I do this if I open the modal via JavaScript, thus:

```
$('#myModal').modal();
```

I have tried various ways of providing parameters, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
         //$('selector-for-modal-body').html(yourdata);
        })`

Answer (score 0):

Passing a button created with jQuery as the second argument worked for me in v3 of Bootstrap

**Code**

```
$('#myModal').modal({}, $('<button/>', {
    "data-context": "OPS"
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this if you are using Bootstrap 3.2.0.

### HTML

```
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="my_id_value">Open Modal</a>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

//triggered when modal is about to be shown

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

//get data-id attribute of the clicked element
var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');

//populate the textbox
$(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="bookId"]').val(bookId);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7FC2/

Comment: Thanks but I know about that way using HTML (from searches I did before asking).  What I am looking for is a way to do the same thing when opening the modal using javascript eg using $('#myModal').modal(some_data_parameters);'

I do know I can achieve the effect by using a global variable, or by creating a temporary button, but I hoped there was an easier way by giving parameters.